# Подскадите, как подправить код, чтобы текст шел вокруг картинки, как на картинке с примером

Tags: javascript, css

```js
var e = document.getElementsByClassName('rotate_text');
for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
  e[i].style.webkitTransform = 'rotateY(' + (i - e.length / 6) * 40 + 'deg) translateZ(250px)';
}
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.wrapp {
  position: absolute;
  perspective: 1000px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  animation: rot 5s linear infinite;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}

.rotate_text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 50px;
}

@keyframes rot {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
    z-index: 5;
  }
  25% {
    z-index: 5;
  }
  50% {
    z-index: 5;
  }
  75% {
    z-index: 5;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(-360deg);
    z-index: 0;
  }
}

.test {
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  z-index: 1;
}

.test img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapp">
    <div class="rotate_text">test</div>
    <div class="rotate_text">test</div>
    <div class="rotate_text">test</div>
    <div class="rotate_text">test</div>
    <div class="rotate_text">test</div>
    <div class="rotate_text">test</div>
    <div class="rotate_text">test</div>
    <div class="rotate_text">test</div>
    <div class="rotate_text">test</div>
    <div class="rotate_text">test</div>
    <div class="rotate_text">test</div>
  </div>
  <div class="test"><img src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/fox/fox_PNG23151.png" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[codepen](https://codepen.io/liza_cheptsova/pen/vYYKLpO)

Comment: сейчас текст идет по кругу, и вокруг оси. А надо, чтобы стоял на месте и как бы бегущая строка шла вокруг картинки, а отдаленный текст заходил за картинку.

Answer (score 0):

Проверив в codepen, установление z-index класса test на 5 или выше, даёт желаемый результат.

```
.test {
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    z-index: 6;
}
```

К сожалению я не очень хорошо еще разбираюсь в тонкостях CSS чтобы объяснить почему, кроме очевидного, что через z-index, но может кто-то поможет.

Также, в JS петле, лучше сохранить длину, чтобы не подсчитывать каждый раз. Мелочь, но все-таки! Это на stackoverflow на советуют.

```
var e = document.getElementsByClassName('rotate_text');
for (var i = 0, l=e.length; i < l; i++) {
  e[i].style.webkitTransform = 'rotateY(' + (i - l/ 6) * 40 + 'deg) translateZ(250px)';
}
```